# How to show two different error messages based on a range of two dates in angular 7 and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, date, validation

I have to validate moveindate with respect to purchase date and effective date. the condition is it should be in range between purchase date and effective date. So in my ts file I wrote this code:

```
moveInDateRange = [
 DateStringService.toDate(purchaseDate), 
 DateStringService.toDate(policyEffectiveDate)
];
```

But in HTML I have to show two different error messages, in two different scenerios.

1. move-in date must be on or after your purchase date
2. move-in date must be on or before your policy effective date

so I wrote the code like this:

```
<div *ngIf="moveindate < finalDetails.property.Details.moveInDateRange[0].toLocaleDateString()">
                    <span class="txt txt--error">move-in date must be on or after your purchase date</span>
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="moveindate > finalDetails.property.Details.moveInDateRange[1].toLocaleDateString()">
                    <span class="txt txt--error">move-in date must be on or before your policy effective date</span>
                </div>
```

But the problem is it is always showing the second error message.

can you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: moveindate are string? what king of input are you using: mat-datepicker, ng-datepicker a input type="date? Are you using Reactive forms or template driven form? Are you using a custom validator or not?

Comment: I am using reactive form. moveindate is string. input type is also string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your condition is not valid since you are comparing by strings. Did you tried with Dates.compare() ?

You should find what you want here :

- https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-5.php
- https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/compare-dates

Comment: how to compare in html ?

Comment: Can we compare the dates in html?

Comment: In pure html no, you will need something else to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use reactiveForm, you can create a custom validator. You can make the custom validator over the FormControl "moveinDate", but you need remember updateAndvalidity the control when change "purchaseDate" and "policyEffectiveDate"

Here we go!

I imagine you has some like

```
  form = new FormGroup({
    purchaseDate: new FormControl(),
    policyEffectiveDate: new FormControl(),
    moveinDate: new FormControl(null, this.validationBetween())
  });
```

after create the form, we need take account when change the purchaseDate and policyEffectiveDate, we are going to use rxj operator "merge" that emit a new value when one or another FormControl change his value. But as merge only emit one value after the two FormControls change, we are going to use startWith also

```
  ngOnInit(){
    merge(this.form.get('purchaseDate').valueChanges.pipe(
                     startWith(this.form.value.purchaseDate)),
    this.form.get('policyEffectiveDate').valueChanges.pipe(
                     startWith(this.form.value.policyEffectiveDate))
    ).subscribe(_=>{
      this.form.get('moveinDate').updateValueAndValidity()
    })
  }
```

Our custom validator can return an object with the same property: "error" in both cases or with different properties if we want make differences.

```
  validationBetween(){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      const parent=control.parent as FormGroup
      if (parent)
      {
        const purchaseDate=parent.get('purchaseDate')
        const policyEffectiveDate=parent.get('policyEffectiveDate')
        if (!purchaseDate.value || !policyEffectiveDate.value || !control.value)
        return null;
        if (purchaseDate.value>control.value)
           return {error:"moveInDate should be greater or equal than "+purchaseDate.value}
        if (policyEffectiveDate.value<control.value)
           return {error:"policyEffectiveDate should be less or equal than "+policyEffectiveDate.value}
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

If we choose the same property we can use simply

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="date" formControlName="purchaseDate">
  <input type="date" formControlName="policyEffectiveDate">
  <input type="date" formControlName="moveinDate">
  {{form.get('moveinDate').errors?.error}}
</form>
```

If we choose that in one case return,e.g. `{errorLess:"...."}` and `{errorGreater:"..."}` we can use some like

```
<div *ngIf="form.get('moveinDate').errors?.errorLess">Error less</div>
<div *ngIf="form.get('moveinDate').errors?.errorGreater">Error Greater</div>
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nctrv3?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

NOTE: I use a input type="date", really I like more use angular material date picker or ng-bootstrap datePicker. In this case we need convert the "dates" to string in the way "yyyy-mm-dd" or use getTimer() to get the milliseconds before compare them